# Javascript - generate an anchor with both the href and download atrributes

Tags: javascript, download, anchor, href

I'm trying to dynamically generate an anchor for a given content (documents and/or images stored on Cloudinary.io, in this case), but the documents I'm storing have a hash value rather than a filename (i.e.: `c9eed62bd1534c382a3b89241b24b1ddd17b3793` instead of `sample.pdf`).

Here's the function I'm using to generate the anchor:

```
function download(url, download) {
    if (url) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');

        if (a) {
            a.href = url;
            a.download = download || '';
            a.target = '_blank';
            a.click();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I have is, when I execute the function, the browser downloads the file for me, but with the name in the `href` attribute rather than the `download` attribute.

This is the event I use to fire the download:

```
$('.link').on('click', function (e) {
    download($(this).data('url'), $(this).data('name'));
});
```

And this is a sample HTML element containing the data to trigger the event:

```
<span class="link" data-url="http://res.cloudinary.com/dxsky7h00/raw/upload/v1483364241/627ec3e4afa08749ac4aff8d2917a38f586a5790" data-name="fs545554545454.xls"><i class="icon-file-o"></i>fs545554545454</span>
```

Maybe I understood the `download` attribute for the `<a>` element in a wrong way, but I thought, when specified, it forces the browser to download the resource rather than trying to open it on one hand and, on the other hand, if `download="something"` is used, the resource will be downloaded with the name being 'something' rather than what's in the `href` attribute.

What am I missing for this sample function to work?

**EDIT** I'm currently testing this on Chrome 55.0.2883.87 (64-bit), but as [this entry on caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/download/embed/description) states, it's compatible

Comment: http://caniuse.com/download/embed/description

Comment: How do you call your function?

Comment: @haim770 While it doesn't visibly work on Safari and some others, I'm testing this on Chrome and it's not working, so it's not about compatibility

Comment: @mplungjan download($(this).data('url'), $(this).data('name'));

Comment: And now show the html that creates `$(this)` - We need to see the format of the name - create a [mcve] please - for example is it a button, an image, a div?

Comment: is the href cross-origin?

Comment: @mplungjan <span class="enlace" data-url="http://res.cloudinary.com/dxsky7h00/raw/upload/v1483364241/627ec3e4afa08749ac4aff8d2917a38f586a5790" data-nombre="fs545554545454.xls"><i class="icon-file-o"></i>fs545554545454</span>

Comment: And now update your question with the contents of your comments and show where the event handler is assigned on the span. Please help us help you!

Comment: I see data-nombre by the way...

Comment: @mplungjan my bad... corrected :P

Answer (score 0):

@tsh asked the right question. The problem lies in the fact the `href` attribute references an external resource, hence we're dealing with a cross-origin reference and the browser won't let me download it with another name.

I tested it with a local file and it worked, so the problem lies within my implementation. Thanks to all anyway :)